# Размер БД после удаления данных

Tags: firebird

Создаю базу в IBExpert, версии 2.0.
Пишу в базу, база растет.
Но если удалить данные из базы, база не уменьшается в размерах.
Как можно это решить?

Comment: @Raaur, видимо у Firebird отсутствует команда [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html). [Нашёл обсуждение на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662431/how-do-i-optimize-table-after-delete-many-records) этого вопроса. Ознакомьтесь.

Comment: Вообще ее кто-нибудь сейчас еще использует?

Я думал, что ее уже давно похоронили...

Comment: А что щас используют из бесплатного?

Comment: @Raaur Честно говоря, я о ней только слышал и один раз застал, когда переходили с нее на PostgreSQL. Сделал вывод, что она все-таки чем-то не устраивает людей. Сам я с базами мало работаю.

Comment: @Raaur, если просто файловая, то sqlite или какая-нибудь h2, если с полноценным сервером - mysql, postgresql или более специфичные решения типа mariadb, их сейчас пруд пруди.

Comment: ммм  ну когда проектировался проект sqlite был совсем сырой. а вот  h2 упусти из виду. Там маленький проект и вполне достаточно FB.  Спс за инфу буду иметь введу

Comment: @Raaur sqlite уже готов для внедрения. Много где пользуют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq41/

Если коротко, то тут проблема в том, что освобождение пространства это такая же затратная операция, как и дефрагментация, единственный способ получить назад место - это сделать backup, при котором произойдёт сборка мусора и развернуть его назад.

Answer (score 1):

Как сказано в [Firebird FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq41/):

Уменьшение файла — это ресурсоёмкая операция, как, например, дефрагментация. Вместо этого освобождённые страницы будут использованы впоследствии, когда вы добавите новые данные.

Если вам нужно освободить место на диске, вы можете выполнить создание бэкапа и восстановление из него. Чтобы ускорить операцию, рекомендуется выполнять её с флагом `-G`, чтобы не выполнять сборку мусора, которая бесполезна при последовательном выполнении backup и restore.